# Infinity.js (lazy rendering) for large html tables, prototype.js example included

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

How to lazily load/render very big html tables while maintaining performance, especially in IE?

I have found a prototype.js plugin (https://github.com/jbrantly/bigtable/, post: http://blog.jbrantly.com/2010/03/really-really-big-html-table.html, demo:http://jbrantly.github.io/bigtable/). I wondering if there is a jQuery-based solution.

I am also exploring setting defined width/heights (both in css and using col attribute) for cells to prevent re-layout on window resize, but still maintaining responsiveness through media queries.

Any other thoughts or ideas on how to improve performance on pages with large html tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can run a `setInterval` and render the table in parts, the user won't see whole big table at once anyway.

You can increase the performance by updating the DOM once/few times instead of hundreds of times, create the table as a string with JavaScript and later append it to the DOM.

You can also improve the performance of the loops a little by saving the lenght of an array, it will help in older browsers.

```
for (var i = 0, ilen = a.length; i < ilen; ++i) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid). Pretty amazing performance, uses jQuery, mature codebase, still maintained.

Only caveat is no IE6 support — but even people who need to support IE don't often need to support that far back these days.